# Spotfire In Statements, Ranges, Etc

Tags: spotfire

I come from an SQL background, so trying to limit data coming into the Spotfire project using the expression builder has become a challenge. For instance, I can't seem to find an example of the equivalent of the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE COLUMN IN ('X','Y','Z')
```

It's probably staring me in the face, but the only examples I can find are for IF and CASE statements, which are not what I want.

Another example is trying to find an example of an equivalent BETWEEN statement (i.e, WHERE COLUMN BETWEEN 1 and 20). I found the RANGE function, but I have not found any good examples on how to use it.

Does anyone have any suggestions to sites which would provide some examples of what should be easy expressions to create? The online Spotfire guide is not that helpful and my google fu has failed to find anything.

If you could give me some pointers on the two statements above, I would really appreciate it!

Thanks!

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do. The custom expressions (I guess this is what you are referring to) are designed to create a column or a view not to filter.  Your SQL statement can for instance be achieved using the filter panel (from the menu on top View > Filters)

Comment: You could watch the Dr Spotfire series on YouTube for pointers. For instance, Filter and Limit Data across Spotfire Visualizations here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rFe5sWbp5pE

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get some suggestions from some friends of mine. Gaia, thank you for your suggestion--YouTube was one suggestion I did receive. I also heard about community.tibco.com, which I will be checking out.